# Убрать вертикальный скрол ,но оставить горизонтальный свойством overflow-y: scroll?

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

мой код,но появляется автоматом вертикальная полоска

```
.new-box-container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    width: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вам надо использовать именно горизонтальный скролл, то необходимо воспользоваться свойством

```
overflow-x: scroll;
```

А overflow-y либо вообще не трогать, либо установить в положение

```
overflow-y: hidden;
```